I wanted decompress .xz file in cpp using lzma in chunks i.e decompress some data and the read in async fashion
I am doing this using lzma strm decoder and maintain position variable till we have read the file and using seekg(postion) before decoding but
when second time function is called but I am receiving the LMA_FORMAT_ERROR
pseudo code below
std::size_t LzmaReader::Impl::read(void* buffer, std::size_t size){
    m_inFile.open(m_path , std::ios::binary);
    m_strm = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
    m_action = LZMA_RUN;
    const std::string msg = "unable to open xz file \"" + m_path + '"';

    if (not m_inFile) {
        throw std::system_error(std::make_error_code((std::errc)errno), msg);
    }
    auto rc = lzma_stream_decoder(&m_strm, UINT64_MAX, 0);
    if (rc != LZMA_OK) {
        throw Exception(msg + ": " + Exception::getErrorCodeString(rc), rc);
    }

    m_strm.next_in = nullptr;
    m_strm.avail_in = 0;
    m_strm.next_out = m_decodedBuffer;
    m_strm.avail_out = BUF_SIZE;

    std::size_t totalBytesRead = 0;

    std::int64_t bytesToRead = size;
    m_inFile.seekg(m_pos);
    while(bytesToRead > 0)
    {
        if (m_strm.avail_in == 0 and !m_inFile.eof())
        {
            m_inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_encodedBuffer), BUF_SIZE);

            // check for IO errors
            if (m_inFile.bad())
            {
                const std::string msg2 = "Error while reading xz file \"" + m_path + '"';
                throw std::system_error(std::make_error_code((std::errc)errno), msg);
            }

            m_strm.next_in = m_encodedBuffer;
            m_strm.avail_in = m_inFile.gcount();

            if (m_inFile.eof())
            {
                m_action = LZMA_FINISH;
            }
        }

        m_strm.next_out = static_cast<std::uint8_t *>(buffer) + totalBytesRead;
        m_strm.avail_out = size;

        rc = lzma_code(&m_strm, m_action);

        if (rc == LZMA_STREAM_END or m_strm.avail_out == 0)
        {
            auto writeSize = size - m_strm.avail_out;
            totalBytesRead += writeSize;
            bytesToRead -= writeSize;
        }

        if (rc != LZMA_OK)
        {
            if (rc == LZMA_STREAM_END)
            {
                break;
            }

            throw Exception("unable to read from xz file \"" + m_path + ": "
                                + Exception::getErrorCodeString(rc),rc);
        }
    }

    m_pos += totalBytesRead;
    lzma_end(&m_strm);
    m_inFile.close();
    return totalBytesRead;
}

and if i dont close the lzma strm and file error is DATA_CORRUPT

One error you are making is failing to call inputFile.clear() after your while loop. Once the file stream is in an error state you must clear it before any other operation will work.

size_t currentPosition = 0; followed by inputFile.seekg(currentPosition); has no effect. What is decompressChunk, it doesn't seem to be part of a known library?

Xz files aren't lzma bitstreams, you'll need to use xzutils to decode them

Code works fine for first call read the line according to buffer size
